# Only the first results of sql show when unhidden

Tags: php, javascript, show-hide

I asked a question earlier about how to hide and show sql results upon a click using jquery. Kudos to Þaw for helping me out...
Now i moved on to something similar yet different, more of a "bug in the code" thing. I have a php file that retrieves all data from a db table, only one row is displayed(the title of my data in the table). Upon clicking the title, a hidden div is shown which returns rest of the data. The issue im encountering here is, with multiple entries in the in the table... The show/hide magic only works with the first row, regardless of which title i click.

this is my js

```
function showDiv() {
if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

and this is my php/html

```
<div><h2 Style="margin:auto;display: block; padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;    background: #e0741b; width: auto;color: white;" onclick="showDiv();"><?php echo   $rows['title']; ?></h2></div>
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">

<strong><h3 style="color:black" ><? echo $rows['name']; ?></h3></strong><br/>

<p style="color: grey; font-size:10pt;"><strong><?php echo $rows['details']; ?>  </strong></p>

<p style="font-size: 10pt;"> <strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $rows['email']; ?></p>

<p style="font-size: 10pt;"> <strong>Phone:</strong> <?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></p>

<p style="font-size: 10pt;"> <strong>Link:</strong> <?php echo $rows['link']; ?></p>


</div>
```

Comment: why do you have dangling `</td></tr>` at the end of the last `<p>`?

Comment: If this code is in a php loop, how many divs with id = hiddenDiv think you have? In that case the HTML is invalid... Maybe you could try to concatenate the id of each row or something to identify each block ... and send this id as param to showDiv...

Comment: @Mate I'm sorry if I may sound a little dumb, I'm a newbie... But when you say "concatenate the id of each row" how would I go about doing that?

Comment: No problem, this is a good place to ask :D . Do you have $rows['id'] or any unique value in your results?

Comment: Aaaah! I see where you going with this, yes I do...

Comment: ;) , check this http://jsfiddle.net/gVru6/ , and replace the '1' and '2' and.... with your unique key. If you do not want to expose the 'id' ... You can create and initialize a variable 'idx' before the loop and increase it at every turn ...

Comment: @Mate aaaaaah man you a genius... ;) Thanks a lot, beer on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not the code I would write**, but using your own code here is how you would solve the hide/show problem: Note the addition of `$rows['id']` this assumes the data has a field called id (change this to whatever the actual unique field name is)

```
    <script>
        function showDiv(id) {
            if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv'+id).style.display == 'block') {
                document.getElementById('hiddenDiv'+id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('hiddenDiv'+id).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
--LOOP STARTS--
    <div>
        <h2 Style="margin:auto; display: block; padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; background: #e0741b; width: auto;color: white;" onclick="showDiv(<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>);"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></h2></div>
    <div id="hiddenDiv<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" style="display:none">
        <strong><h3 style="color:black"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></h3></strong><br />
        <p style="color: grey; font-size:10pt;"><strong><?php echo $rows['details']; ?>  </strong></p>
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $rows['email']; ?></p>
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><strong>Phone:</strong> <?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></p>
        <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><strong>Link:</strong> <?php echo $rows['link']; ?></p>
    </div>
-- LOOP ENDS ---
```

So what you are doing is giving the hiddendiv a unique id and then passing that same id to the show/hide js function so it knows which one to show and hide

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one ID attribute value per DOM element. Each ID must be unique to the document.

Comment: My first guess was it might be the ID conflicting, but I'm not sure of how to resolve this to making it get different unique ID's... I thought of maybe using "class", but I thought since the js is saying "getElementById" then it would cause me all sorts of errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Where's the loop? Am I missing something? In your hidden DIV there should be something like the below. It's a generic table, adjust it for what you're doing. I'm not sure which database connection you're using, this is assuming PDO.

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>details</td><td>email</td><td>phone</td></tr></thead>';

while ($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['details'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I know it's different to the layout you want, but this is the general idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Felix says "The show/hide magic only works with the first row". So I was guessing that the hide/show is working just fine, but only one row was showing (because he hasn't specified any loop in the code he's shown). I see now what he was getting at, the whole code block is in a loop (not shown).

Comment: And it only worked with the first row because each row had the same ID.